Issue in vue js 2 hot reloading is not working
Vue.js 2 project that i newly installed by vue cli. hot reloading doesn't working.

{
  "name": "blog",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}

and console error is
WebSocketClient.js:13 WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.43.65:8081/ws' failed:
hot reloading should occur automatically data must be change without manual reloading

Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. I'm positive package.json is not enough, otherwise everyone would have the problem as you with vue cli, which is not the case
